# WooCommerce checkout return empty

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I am trying to setup an online services base store using the [2checkout plugin](https://codecanyon.net/item/better-2checkout-payment-gateway-for-woocommerce/16555874,). I am getting this javascript error on the checkout page:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'o.reload')
success (checkout.min.js:1:9640)
i (jquery.js:2:27455)
fireWith (jquery.js:2:28215)
y (jquery.js:4:22733)
c (jquery.js:4:26927)
```

and WC checkout ajax return empty with 200 status

Comment: Have you contacted the plugin developer about this? It's difficult to help you debug a commercial plugin.

Comment: This is not plugin issue, i disable this plugin getting same error :(